# Use JSON property accessor in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am consuming JSON file that returns

```
"Rows": [
   {
      "Id": "Row1",
      "Dataset": "Person",
      "ColumnFields": [
        "John",
        "attr.0.PYNM",
        "attr.1.PYUV",
        "attr.2.PHGT"
   }
    ]
```

Once I have parsed the JSON to hash, how can I use the keys `attr.0.PYNM` to access a hash returned from an API response? The API response is something like

```
{
 attr:
  [
    {
     'PYNM' => 'value1'
    },
    {
     'PYUV' => 'value2'
    }
 ]
}
```

So something like `response['attr'][0]['PYNM']`? I also need to use fetch to be able to define default values if the value returns nil or empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of thing `Enumerable#reduce` is really good for:

```
data = {
  "attr" => [
    { 'PYNM' => 'value1' },
    { 'PYUV' => 'value2' }
  ]
}

def dig(data, key)
  key.split('.').reduce(data) do |current, key_part|
    break if current.nil?
    key_part = Integer(key_part) if current.is_a?(Array)
    current[key_part]
  end
end

p dig(data, "attr.0.PYNM")
# => "value1"

p dig(data, "attr.1")
# => { "PYUV" => "value2" }

p dig(data, "attr.0.QWERTYUIOP")
# => nil

p dig(data, "attr.1.2")
# => nil

p dig(data, "attr.foo")
# => prog.rb:10:in `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "foo" (ArgumentError)
```

Note that in the input I used string keys (`"attr"` instead of `:attr`). You may have to augment the code if your input has both string and symbol keys—or, if you're using Rails, it may be a HashWithIndifferentAccess, which may (or may not) avoid the problem.

Note also that I used `Kernel#Integer` instead of `String#to_i` to do a more strict conversion of array keys. `to_i` would have converted `"foo"` to `0`, which would have yielded a wrong result, so better to use `Integer` to raise an error instead.

There are still cases this doesn't cover, though, e.g. `".foo"` or `"foo..bar"` or `""`.

Comment: Thanks @jordan. Exactly what I was looking for. I owe you a pint.

Answer (score 0):

`"attr.0.PYNM"` is a value of type String, not a key. *ColumnFields* is an array here, its content can only be accessed with indexes (or using `Array.each`).

The way to access it:

```
hash['Rows'][0]['ColumnFields'][1] // For "attr.0.PYNM"
```

Comment: @a-gille I actually want to use the string `attr.0.PYNM` to get value out of an API response. The above file is just a template for the API response. So the API will return something like `{attr: ['PYNM' => 'value']}

Comment: So just split this string with `String.split`

Answer (score 0):

You are right. If your response is this one:

```
{
 attr:
  [
    {
     'PYNM' => 'value1'
    },
    {
     'PYUV' => 'value2'
    }
 ]
}
```

You will need to do the following

```
response[:attr][0]['PYNM']
```

(Note attr as a symbol an not as a string). Hope it helps you.